# How to write Subquery in Entity Framework using Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Hi i want this in LINQ Entity framework.......

```
select Empame,EmpSalary,EmpDepartment,(select CountryName from Countries c where c.ID = Employees.EmpCountry) as Country,(select StateName from dbo.States c where c.ID = Employees.EmpState)as States from Employees
```

I tried This Its givning error enter code here

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var Employee = (from e in _db.Employee
    select new 
    {
    Empame = e.Empame,
    EmpSalary = e.EmpSalary,
    EmpDepartment = e.EmpDepartment,
    EmpCountry = (from c in _db.Country
    where (c.ID.ToString() == e.EmpCountry)
    select c),
    EmpState = (from s in _db.States
    where (s.ID.ToString() == e.EmpState)
    select s)});
    return View(Employee);
}
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

Answer (score 0):

```
from e in Employees 
from c in Countries
from s in States
where c.ID == e.EmpCountry
where s.ID == e.EmpState
select new {
    EmpName = e.EmpName,
    EmpSalary= e.EmpSalary,
    EmpDepartment= e.EmpDepartment,
    Country = c.Single(),
    State = s.Single()
}
```

BUT a better way is to make your model have navigation properties to the Country and state tables. If you generate your EDMX file off a DB with foreign keys the navigation properties will be created automatically. This will mean you will simply be able to use:

```
from e in Employees.Include(em=>em.Country).include(em=>em.State)
select e;
```

The actual error you are getting is because your view is expecting a string not an IQueriable. To change this make sure you specify the model type in the view

Comment: from e in Employees  from c in Countries from s in States where c.ID.ToString == e.EmpCountry where s.ID.ToString==e.EmpStateselect new {     EmpName = e.EmpName,EmpSalary= e.EmpSalary,EmpDepartment= e.EmpDepartment, Country = c.Single(),State = s.Single() } System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`6[System.String,System.Double,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Comment: "The actual error you are getting is because your view is expecting a string not an IQueriable. To change this make sure you specify the model type in the view"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to return a non materialized query. Try to add `.Single(), .FirstOrDefault()` etc.:

```
var Employee = (from e in _db.Employee
    select new 
    {
    Empame = e.Empame,
    EmpSalary = e.EmpSalary,
    EmpDepartment = e.EmpDepartment,
    EmpCountry = (from c in _db.Country
    where (c.ID.ToString() == e.EmpCountry)
    select c),
    EmpState = (from s in _db.States
    where (s.ID.ToString() == e.EmpState)
    select s)}).FirstOrDefault();
```